How can I check if a moderator has already checked my flag?
I flagged the comment thread on this question: Does mental rigidity cause psychological problems?
How can I check if a moderator has already checked?

I've edited this question to reflect the actual useful question in there. The rest was part of the conflict and of no interest here.

Go look at your flag summary - you'll see the flag you raised there. When it has been handled, it will no longer have the text "active" after it in the list.
